# How to extend given function to Constant when Condition on function given

Tags: complex-analysis

> Suppose f is non-vanishing holomorphic function in $\mathbb D$ and if $|z|=1\to |f(z)|=1$ then we have to show that f is constant

I had learned to extend function using Schwartz reflection Priciple to lower half plane with the condition given
As per Hint Provided, I have to extend f to whole $\mathbb C$ by $f(z)=1/ \overline{{f(\bar{z})}}$ whenever $|z|>1$
I do not know How to proceed?
Any Help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My attempt:
[I am New to complex Analysis Just Learned Scwarz reflection principal,I had solved above using that .I wanted to check my approch. Have a look at solution ,If there is gaps in proof if you think , I will happy to see that]

As given $f$ is non vanishing continous function on closed  Unit disc and holomorphic on unit disc.
We have to extend function all over c.
We have 3 partition , Inside  disc , On boundary and outside disk
We had already definied function on first 2
for 3rd
$|z|>1$ take conjugate to make anticonformal $z\to \bar z$ thentake reciprocal $\bar z\to 1/\bar z$ now $|1/\bar z|<1$ so $f(1/\bar z)$ definied 
To make it conformal map again we will take conjugate and reciprocal......[why reciprocal? see downward]
$1/\overline{f(1/\bar z)}$
$f:C\to C$ defined as 
$$F(z)=f(z),|z|\leq1$$  
  $$=1/\overline{f(1/\bar z)},|z|>1$$

Now time to use non vanishing assumption that means $f(z)\neq 0 for |z|<1$
 by defination [use of  reciprocal] for |z|>1 f(z) become bounded.
Now by symmetry principal we have extended funciton to whole $\mathbb C$ and we have bounded function.
By Lioveilie theorem it is constant

Answer (score 2):

Since $f$ is holomorphic and non-vanishing on $\mathbb{D}$, $1/f$ is also holomorphic on $\mathbb{D}$. By [Maximum Modulus Principle](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MaximumModulusPrinciple.html) applied to $f$ and $1/f$, your condition implies that
$$
1 \leq |f(z)| \leq 1 \Rightarrow |f(z)| = 1
$$
for every $z\in \mathbb{D}$. Then $f$ achieves maximum modulus in the interior of its domain which implies that it is constant, again by Maximum Modulus Principle.

Another way to approach this is to use [Schwarz Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lemma#Schwarz%E2%80%93Pick_theorem), not the reflection principle.